# Changing default sorting on datatables jQuery Bootstrap plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, sorting, datatables

Here's an example datatable:

http://jsfiddle.net/xF8hZ/10/

currently am using this JS to initialize the table:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#example").dataTable({
    "sDom": "<'row'<'col-lg-11'i><'col-lg-1'>r>t<'row'<'col-lg-6'l><'col-lg-6'p>
  });
});
```

I would like to change the default sort order from ascending to descending, how would I go about doing so? I have tried:

```
"order": [[ 3, "desc" ]]
```

however, that breaks the tables sorting buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This code seems to work :*

**JS**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#example").dataTable({
    "sDom": "<'row'<'col-lg-11'i><'col-lg-1'>r>t<'row'<'col-lg-6'l><'col-lg-6'p>>",
        "order":[[3, 'desc']]
  });
});
```

**Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/xF8hZ/11/